# No implementation found after Upgrading pre 1.12 Android projects

Tags: android, flutter

I have to upgrade flutter android as here '[Upgrading pre 1.12 Android projects](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)'

but after I done I run app in android emulator it's working but give me error `No implementation found` almost all package give me that issue

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on
>   channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
>
> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
>    getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
>
> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on 
>   channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

my android project is kotlin so at first step of structure of
 Upgrading-pre-1.12 i delete `MainActivity.kt` instead of
 `MainActivity.java`

I tried `flutter clean` and `flutter upgrade`

> ae24f1841..e43fd1c54  master     -> origin/master
>   Updating cf37c2cd0..27321ebba
>    24 files changed, 651 insertions(+), 218 deletions(-)
>   Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
>   Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable •
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>   Framework • revision 27321ebbad (2 weeks ago) • 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
>   Engine • revision 2994f7e1e6
>   Tools • Dart 2.7.0

I tried close emulator and vscode and uninstall app but the issue still exist

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling all the packages

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
```

Comment: still issue exists

Comment: can you try delete the application manually from the emulator? then build again.

Comment: yes i did that and closed the emulator itself , and still exist also